# Connection between ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm a newbie and I have to build a web for my thesis. I've learned from videos on Youtube and code follow the instruction but I have a problem :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
> HResult=0x80131904
> Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
> Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider

I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for your reading and support!

Here is my code:

```
public class DBIO
{
    MyDB mydb = new MyDB();
    
    public user GetObj_user(string fname)
    {
        //Không sử dụng Parameters
        //string SQL = "SELECT [fullname] FROM [user] WHERE ([fullname]='"+fname+"')";
        //return mydb.Database.SqlQuery<user>(SQL).FirstOrDefault();

        //Có sử dụng Parameters
        return mydb.Database.SqlQuery<user>("SELECT [fullname] FROM user WHERE [fullname]=@L", new SqlParameter("@L", fname)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: `user` is a language keyword, as in `create user`, `alter user` and `drop user`. Have you considered quoting the word like you are quoting column names? e.g.: `[user]`

Comment: I have tried it but it still "Invalid object name user" :(

Comment: `Invalid object name user` is a different error. In the context of your `select` statement it means that the database that your code is connecting to has no table nor view named `user`. Maybe the connection string is connecting to the wrong database, or maybe the table/view hasn't been created yet?

Comment: I have checked but that is not my problem

Comment: That is *definitely* your problem. That is what that error is: you are connecting to the wrong database, or have the wrong default schema, or you don't have permissions to it, or the table/view simply doesn't exist. Please supply a [mcve]

Comment: I will try to research, thanks all!!!

Comment: does it work without the parameter?